# how to handle Sorry we have detected unusual traffic from your network issue while automating Lazada webpage?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate the website https://www.lazada.com.my/# with selenium and Java where I want to login with the username and password but when  I am clicking on Login button then I am getting the error message pop up as "Sorry We have detected unusual traffic from your network".

Can you please help me with which respective chromeoption need to be used to handle this message

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to automate a website you do not own?

Comment: same feature is also developed by my dev and they want to ensure that this new feature works fine in production environment

Comment: Apparently they have mechanisms in place to detect exactly what you are trying to to do.   The solution is most likely to contact them to get an agreement to allow you to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try login only one instance from your machine, they are detecting more than one session from your machine.